# Access non-generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have an entity of type `IList<MyClass>` that I want to map to a list of type `IList<MyMappedClass>` while keeping the same underlying collection type.

By this I mean if the instance happens to be of type `List<MyClass>` it should be mapped to `List<MyMappedClass>` and `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to `ObservableCollection<MyMappedClass>`.

What I did so far is I can find the generic type of the list like this:

```
Type listType = myList.GetType(); //myList type: List<T> or ObservableCollection<T>
Type listItemType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

I know that I can do this:

```
Type myListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listItemType );
```

I cannot do that:

```
Type myListType = myList.GetType().MakeGenericType(listItemType );
```

Because it is already generic. What I am looking for is the following:

```
Type myListType = myList.GetType().GotNonGenericType().MakeGenericType(listItemType );
```

where `GotNonGenericType()` is a placeholder for the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: "Magical" covariance beyond interfaces? Hmm. Unless this is on a performance critical path, I think I'd just `myList.Cast<MyClass>().ToList()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will return a generic definition of a type, e.g. `List<>` from `List<Whatever>`. And then you can create a type with a generic arguments you want with [`Type.MakeGenericType(params Type[] typeArguments)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var list    = new List<int>();
var type    = myList.GetType();                        // ~ typeof(List<int>)
var generic = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();         // ~ typeof(List<>)
var newType = generic.MakeGenericType(typeof(string)); // ~ typeof(List<string>)
```

Variable `newType` contains what you trying to achieve.